# datbase.php of cakephp not uploading to github

Tags: cakephp, github, cakephp-1.2, github-for-windows

I have recently started using GitHub. I am uploading my cakephp website.
Also, I am using GitHUb for windows, http://windows.github.com/

Now, after I added my CakePHP files -> committed the changes -> synced, I do not see my app/database.php file being uploaded.

I checked the repository through browser, but still can't find the database.php file.

I have re-installed GitHub for windows, created a new repository, again added the files to it, but same result.

Please help, what is the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @roine , I had the following in my gitignore file
tmp/*
config/database.php
app/tmp/*
app/config/database.php
!empty

Comment: @roine this worked.. please add that as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your .gitignore file and commit again.

But database.php is in your .gitignore is for a security reason. It may contain sensitive data, double check it before pushing.

Comment: I have the repository as private.. but yes if I had it as public.. I agree that would have lead to security issues..